# Get image invalid php

Tags: php

This code not display image ??

This code does not market it displays the image gif how to fix it

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Type: image/GIF");
$look = imagecreatefromgif("http://habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure='lg-3088-110-1408.sh-3068-110-1408.ea-3168-110.ch-3215-99.hr-3163-61.hd-3103-3&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&img_format=gif");

ImageGif ($look);    
?>
```

The error is:

```
PHP Warning: imagecreatefromgif(): 'habbo.com/habbo-imaging/…; is not a valid GIF file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\avatar.php on line 4

PHP Warning: imagegif() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\avatar.php on line 6
```

Comment: You can't send 2 mime types either, `GIF` should be `gif`. [Enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/) and view the source code of the output to see the error message.

Comment: @Dan [Yes.](http://de2.php.net/ImageGif)

Comment: @deceze oh lol thanks. Didn't know `ImageGif` and `imagegif` was the same. Thanks :-)

Comment: 26-Sep-2014 12:01:11 Europe/Dublin] PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromgif(): 'http://habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure='lg-3088-110-1408.sh-3068-110-1408.ea-3168-110.ch-3215-99.hr-3163-61.hd-3103-3&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&img_format=gif' is not a valid GIF file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\avatar.php on line 4
[26-Sep-2014 12:01:11 Europe/Dublin] PHP Warning:  imagegif() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\avatar.php on line 6

Comment: @cleanguyFr Please edit your question and add that there. It'll be a lot easier to read...

Answer (score 1):

Habbo does not allow PHP to fetch the image.

Verified by changing the user agent:

```
wget -U "PHP/5.3" "http://habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure='lg-3088-110-1408.sh-3068-110-1408.ea-3168-110.ch-3215-99.hr-3163-61.hd-3103-3&direction=3&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&img_format=gif"
```

The downloaded resource will be HTML, not gif.

You *could*, on your own risk due to legal stuff, bypass this by using `curl` and manually set the User agent:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Disclaimer: Habbo obviously does not want scripts to automatically fetch their pictures and if you bypass their restrictions you do this on your own risk.

Comment: Though you should probably take that behaviour as a hint that you shouldn't be doing that...

Answer (score -1):

Not clear what you actually wanna do.
Windows versions of PHP prior to PHP 4.3.0 do not support access of remote files via this function, even if allow_url_fopen is enabled.

Check manual here [php.net Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)

Comment: 4.3.0? Well, if you haven't updated your PHP installation since 2002, I suppose that's a possibility...